# Using arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have few questions with how to use the pointers. I have the following code.

```
float* arr;
arr = (float*) malloc(4*sizeof(float));
float temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

I want to point the `arr` to the `temp` array. How do I do it? Is `arr=&temp` correct?

The output I want is `arr` pointing to the 1D array `{1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I want to point the `arr` to the `temp` array.*

Then, no need to allocate memory to `arr`. Just use `arr = temp;` and you're good to go.

Otherwise, first if you allocate memory and then you *assign* another pointer, you'll be losing the allocated memory, facing a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

---

As per the suggestion in the comment by [Mr. barak manos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382251/barak-manos), it's worthy to mention that in the way described above, `arr` *actually* points to `temp`. Now, if this assignment is done inside a function and `temp` is local to the function, returning `arr` will be UB.

If the case arises, then, you have to use `malloc()` and `memcpy()` to allocate memory to `arr` and copy the contents of `temp` to that memory which has a lifetime until deallocated, so can be returned from a function.

Comment: My temp is a normal float array. I want to point its contents to a pointer array. Can you please write a working code? How do i print the values in the arr?

Comment: @Minions use the indexing `[]` , just as you would have used for `temp`.

Comment: When i did arr=temp, Its printing the address value rather than the content of the array.

Comment: Given the context of this question, I would say there's a plausible probability that OP will try to `return arr`, in which case he (or she) is not really "good to go". You might want to warn him (or her) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments are bit confusing, you use the verb "point" when talking about arrays, which doesn't make sense. Pointers can be made to point at things, but arrays are not pointers so they cannot. The name of an array *acts* as a pointer to the array's first element in some contexts, but it cannot be changed.

To copy the array into dynamic memory, you can do:

```
const float arr[] = { 1.f, 2.f, 4.f, 8.f };
float * const ptr = malloc(sizeof arr);
memcpy(ptr, arr, sizeof arr);
```

Then you can print the copy:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; ++i)
  print("Element #%zu is %f\n", i, ptr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     float *arr;
     int i;
     float temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
     arr=temp;    //initializing with base address of temp
     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
          printf("%f",arr[i]);
       }
    return 0;
}
```

This will print the output .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.Solution using Array of Pointers

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
       float *arr[4];
       float temp[4]={1,2,3,4};
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            arr[i]=&temp[i];
            printf("%f\n",*(arr[i]));
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: she says "My temp is a normal float array. I want to point its contents to a pointer array".so pointer array points the contents of temp array and print the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the base address of the "temp" array to the "arr" pointer by simply doing

> ```
> arr = temp;
> ```

Furthermore, you can set the "arr" pointer to hold the address of an individual member of the array by doing

> ```
> arr = &temp[0] 
> arr = &temp[1] ... etc.
> ```

To print the contents of the array once the pointer is set to the array's base address you can use the ***** operator or simply use indexing with the pointer.

> ```
> printf("array element 1 = %f, element 2 = %f, element 3 = %f, ...",*arr,*(arr+1),*(arr+2), ...);  
> printf("array element 1 = %f, element 2 = %f, element 3 = %f, ...",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2], ...);
> ```

Also remember a "pointer array" is an array of pointers. Each pointer in this array can point to an memory address independent of the other pointers in the array. So no need to allocate memory to the pointer if you want to assign it to a valid memory address.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention when you declared `temp` as `float temp[4] = ...` then the variable `temp` by itself is of type `float*`(pointer)

which means, the assignment `arr = temp` would make `arr` *point* to the same (static) array as `arr` does.

You can play around with this by sending them to a function and observe the behavior.

i already made this demo for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printTmp(int n, int tmp[n]);
int main() {
    printf("  in main\n");
    int* arr= malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    int temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    arr = temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d, ",arr[i]);
    }
    printTmp(4, temp);
    printTmp(4, arr);
    return 0;
}
void printTmp(int n, int tmp[n]) {
    printf("\n \n in Print\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", tmp[i]);
    }
}
```

which yields the output:

```
  in main
1, 2, 3, 4, 

 in Print
1, 2, 3, 4, 

 in Print
1, 2, 3, 4,
```